# StartDate + TaskDays = DueDate

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, start-time

I need help with SharePoint Workflow, I want to add dates based on lookup from a different column.     
For example -

```
Column A (StartDate) + Column B (TaskDays, numbers) = Column C (DueDate)
```

Reason I want to use DueDate its easy to use the same for Task Timelines.
Other wise I am able to create Column D with Calculated field, i.e. =`[StartDate+2]`

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this using SharePoint designer workflow,

1. in Action button on the ribbon , add `add time to date action`
2. in the `days` property , add your Task days field (number type).
3. in `to date` add your start date (date type).
4. the result will be set in the output variable as on the below screens.
5. back to Actions again and add `Set field in current item` action
6. set the due date field with the output date variable.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response A.Saeed, This doesn't work for me as the Task Days are different for each Task. Please see image I just uploaded to my original post

Comment: @GauravKumra sure i understand this , what i meant is to add the task days field in the days property and this field type should be number

Comment: This worked!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks so much, I can't believe how thankful I am to you for this! You saved me on this... If you don't mind I have another query... I am trying to create predecessors for each task, Task2 StartDate is dependant on Task1 EndDate. This is auto task scheduling I used to do in MS Project

Comment: @GauravKumra welcome :) . glad to help, if you could also vote up to the answer will be fine, sure i'll view your other question

Answer (score 0):

You can make it very easy and quickly using Javascript CSOM. First reflect if you really need a column just to add the days. If you don't just put business rules inside a Javascript function. Use a common input field (a date field from your Javascript Framework). Do it in client before submitting. Another approach is just to do it using a Workflow that format and sum the dates. You can save hundreds work hours using SharePoint Workflows. The last option is using a calculated column with an editorial workflow to do the math.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Edvaldo. I have used calculated Column and its not very helpful. Can you guide me with SharePoint WorkFlow? I haven't been able to do this by myself as I am not yet very good at it. Or maybe a link to a blog will also be very helpful. Thank you again!